# Display custom information according to user location FireStore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, geolocation

I'm trying to display custom information according to userLocation(i.g, ft the user is in Los Angeles, He will get Text("X"). If he is in San Diego, he will get Tex("Y")). For this, I'm using Firestore. There, I have a collection called TEST --> auto ID --> "Name": "Test", Los Angeles: :true

This is how I get userLocation:

```
class LocationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    @Published var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var userLocation : CLLocation!
    @Published var userAddress = ""
    @Published var noLocation = false
    
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            self.noLocation = false
            manager.requestLocation()
        case .denied:
            self.noLocation = true
        default:
            self.noLocation = false
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.userLocation = locations.last
        self.extractLocation()
    }
    
    func extractLocation(){
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self.userLocation) { (res, err) in
            guard let safeData = res else {return}
            
            var address = ""
            
         //   address += safeData.first?.name ?? ""
         //   address += ", "
            address += safeData.first?.locality ?? ""
            
            
            self.userAddress = address
       print(address)
        }
    }  
}
```

Then, I have this code to getDocuments:

```
struct Testtt: Identifiable{
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
   
    }
    class TesteViewModel: NSObject,ObservableObject{
    @StateObject var LocationModel = LocationViewModel()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    @Published var testsss = [Testtt]()
    
    
    func testeApp(){
        db.collection("Test").whereField(LocationModel.userAddress, isEqualTo: true).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {return }
            self.testsss = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Testtt in
               let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                
                let name = data["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                
                return Testtt(name: name)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

- Before, instead of `LocationModel.userAddress`, I manually added the location and it worked fine. But, after using it, the project launched but I got 2 error:

Purple error:

> Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.

Thread 1 error:

> Invalid field path (). Paths must not be empty, begin with '.', end with '.', or contain '..'"`

On debug I got:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid field path (). Paths must not be empty, begin with '.', end with '.', or contain '..''

The app crashes right after I press the button that takes me to this class's view

If anyone have any links with more information, I would be grateful to receivw

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that `LocationModel.userAddress` has the right content before it being used? If that string was empty or null, could cause this issue.

Comment: Yes, when user allows location, the name of the city is displayed

Comment: The issue is, that when the user does not allow location an error is thrown?

Comment: If so, using an `if` to check if the location is set would solve the issue